# How to login in a website and submit form using vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I want to make an installing application using vb.net(not asp.net) where i can login to a website and submit form with out using a browser(like facebook@desktop). I have a little knowledge in php,mysql and vb.net. I have never done web application programming in vb.net. I have searched for this in google but didnt find any useful tutorials.if any one of you have a simple code or tutorial for this,can you please paste the link.

Advance thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I see the practicality to doing something like this, but the most direct route would be to use custom HttpRequests and parse the responses. You would need to configure the GET/POST headers of the request, etc, and then you would also have to have a means of rendering or at least parsing through the returned html response.

VB.Net has a browser built into the winforms controls, though. It might be simpler just to embed that into any application you are using.

Comment: A custom HttpRequest seems not to be the easiest approach regarding "I have a little knowledge in php,mysql and vb.net. I have never done web application programming in vb.net"

Comment: @Tim Schmelter: I wasn't shooting for "easy", I was going for direct. I also listed the built-in browser, but by reading OPs question it sounded as if he didn't want any kind of browser usage. Also, the browser being self-contained it becomes difficult to transfer information between the application and the browser object itself.

Comment: I've translated _"with out using a browser(like facebook@desktop)"_ to without ASP.NET(because no experience in web-applications programming) but like facebook@desktop as Winform with builtin Webbrowser.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: Yes, I read your answer. I can see how you translated it. I read a different meaning from it. It is up to OP to decide which suits his answer best. My question for you is: Do you see something explicitly wrong with what I have put up there or are you simply offended that someone offered an alternate idea? I'm having trouble understanding your resistance here.

Comment: I'm not sure why you are feeling offended. I only wanted to say that `HttpRequests` are not the simpliest(but most flexible) approach and might be too tough for a beginner.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: I'm not offended, I just don't understand your resistance to an alternate idea. "Too tough" is not a determination either of us qualified to make for OP, and even beyond that, if someone else has a similar problem, multiple options might help in their research of a solution.

Comment: There was no _resistance_ but a simple comment that your approach might is not the easiest(what I thought OP has asked for). I haven't downvoted or badmouthed your answer and it might be the perfect way for the OP(or someone else) or not.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is the [WebBrowser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx) control.

- [How to: Add Web Browser Capabilities to a Windows Forms Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3s8ys666.aspx#Y0)
- [WebBrowser Control Overview(Windows Forms)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w290k23d.aspx)